# Using an Offline Context in the Web Audio API "shift" the signal of ~264 samples

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

The issue is very simple.

If I instantiate a `OfflineAudioContext`, create a bufferSource, run it through a Compressor node (or a Panner) and wait for the `.oncomplete` event, the resulting `e.renderedBuffer` contains the processed source, only shifted about 264 samples to the right (from my empirical evidence).

This means that the first 264 samples of the resulting buffer are 0, and the last samples are truncatd early. The resulting buffer length is the same of the source buffer.

Is this a known behaviour?

Comment: The DSP that you are adding to your audio chain adds latency to the chain. In order to perform some signal processing tasks, you need more data to hand than just the current sample, especially if it involves any sort of filtering/convolution. This necessarily adds latency to the audio path. It's possible that the compressor algorithm will require some lookahead... seems unusual for a panner though.

Comment: The Panner seems to add more, about 256 samples (it's hard to tell). By the way, if every node has a fixed lookahead, the offline context should handle this and return the right signal (offsetting it of an amount equal to the sum of the lookaheads). There's no way for the user to tell how much samples is the lookahead for a given graph, and the result is still truncated at the end. This makes the offline context pretty much useless (what's the point of having a clicking, truncated output?)

Comment: Given the extended complexity that is given to the [job of panning](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#attributes-15) (e.g. it's more of a 3d audio "spatializer" than a simple panner), it's no longer surprising to me that it requires lookahead. It's not unusual to pad audio with silence to allow time for DSP to settle down back to zero.

Comment: The default Panner mode is HRTF, which is significant DSP.  (This may change.)

Comment: @cwilso, so this behaviour is expected and confirmed? Is there a workaround to get precise output, without offset? Or at least to get the expected offset, forge a larger buffer and trim it subsequently? I'm making an advanced audio editor, and this behaviour destroys a lot of assumptions.

Comment: @spender: I can pad the audio with zeros, but without knowing the offset for a given graph, it can never work.

Comment: Do you see the same shift in all browsers?

Comment: @aldel - I only tried in Chrome.

Comment: The behavior of the nodes isn't strictly defined by the spec (yet), so it's not well-defined.  I'd expect an HRTF panner to add some latency, though.  Not positive about compression.